# Taking runtime permission error occurs E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NanumGothic.ttf

Tags: android, android-fragments

I searched a lot on google and stackoverflow i got this error

> E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NanumGothic.ttf  in fragment and fragment reloaded after that

please help me for this?I am taking runtime permission after the allow button fragment reloaded.

```
  if (PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {



                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

                    // ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 0);
                } else {


                    //opening an intent


                }
```

here is my logcat.

```
    Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
 Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
 addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NanumGothic.ttf
 addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf
 addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/MTLmr3m.ttf
 getServiceInstance failed!
 ssl=0x7fb2458980 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7f8bd7e360 arg=0x0
ssl=0x7fb2458980 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
```

here is my dependencies

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

It perfectly fine if i create other project but why its not working at my side?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: fragment is reloading after pressing allow button runtime permission.?

Comment: Why don't you simply put your custom font in the `assets/fonts` folder and use it from there, as usual?

Comment: @Rotwang yes fonts are already in assets/fonts.:)

Comment: Then why are you trying to copy your fonts here `/system/fonts/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the weird solution

In your build gradle must have the targetsdkversion. I am removing for the development purpose.so fragment reloading stops after adding that.

Answer (score 4):

in my case ,it was because the ttf resource borken, so i re-copy it and fix

It might be a zip/unzip issue or copy/paste issue. So better to make sure if you are using a correct file with correct extension and just delete the existing and copy it again from the original source.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   verifyStoragePermissions(this);
 }
  public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
// Check if we have read or write permission
      int writePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
int readPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

if (writePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || readPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // We don't have permission so prompt the user
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
    activity, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}
```

}

Comment: use this in mainfiest file   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: run time permit ion will come may be after marshmallow its working for me.use in main activity or you home activity code as is as .

Answer (score 1):

May be you try to use methods that are not exist in old OS versions.
So, try this:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void if60level() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
//yourcode

        } else {
//nothing to do
        }
    }

private boolean canAll() {
        return (canAccessLocation() && canCoarseLocation() && canGetAccounts());
    }
```